# Yii2 - dataProvider related models are not set

Tags: yii2, dataprovider

I have following SearchModel `ComputerSearch`, where I do a join for the query (I have to filter for a field of the related table):

```
class ComputerSearch extends Computer {

  public function search($params) {
      $query = Computer::find();
      $query->innerJoinWith('mainboard');

      $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
          'query' => $query,
      ]);

      $this->load($params);

      if (!$this->validate()) {
          return $dataProvider;
      }

      return $dataProvider;
  }
}
```

When I print the query, with `var_dump($query->createCommand()->rawSql);` and execute the output, I will get all the data of Computer and Mainboard (its a 1:1 relation!).

But: `$dataProvider->models[0]->mainboard` is always null even though there is data in the database.
If i take out the line with `$query->innerJoinWith('mainboard');`, `$dataProvider->models[0]->mainboard` shows the relatied model correctly (and there is actually one in db). Can anybody tell me, why the related models in `$dataProvider` are not been setted correctly when I join `mainboard`?

Comment: In Computer class you should have relation called getMainboard() which will define relation. `mainboard` in this case is not table name, it is relation name.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bug of Yii framework :)
I had the same problem:

- Try to use a FULL OUTER JOIN with the Join method instead of an INNER JOIN
- $query->join(Computer::tableName(), Computer::tableName() . '.id = ' = ' . Mainboard::tableName() . '.id') or something like this

Comment: Thanks a lot that works fine. I hope I will find a nicer solution for this.

  $query = Computer::find()
          ->join('FULL OUTER JOIN', Mainboard::tableName(), Mainboard::tableName() . '.computer_id = ' . Computer::tableName() . '.id');

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = self::find();
$query->innerJoin(Mainboard::tableName(), 'computer.mainboard_id=mainboard.id')
      ->select('computer.*, mainboard.*');
```

Try this

Answer (score -1):

```
`$dataProvider->models[0]->mainboard`  this will give you only result
```

of first record and there may be chance that for first record of `computer`
have no `mainboard` either use  `loop` to print data  or  you use `$dataProvider->getModels()` you will find relational data in each computer data.

**And**

**mainboard should have relation with computer like :
In computer model :**

```
public function getMainboard(){
   return $this->hasMany(Mainboard::className(), ['computer_id', 'id']);
}
```